# Datetime progressive sum PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, aggregate, datetime

my first question here, but I looked in many other places and could not find the answer to my problem.

```
 id | track_seg_id |        time         
----+--------------+---------------------
  1 |            0 | 2020-05-23 07:45:32
  2 |            0 | 2020-05-23 07:46:04
  3 |            0 | 2020-05-23 07:46:53
  4 |            0 | 2020-05-23 07:46:58
  5 |            0 | 2020-05-23 07:47:03
  6 |            0 | 2020-05-23 07:47:08
  7 |            0 | 2020-05-23 07:47:11
  8 |            0 | 2020-05-23 07:47:16
  9 |            0 | 2020-05-23 07:47:20
 10 |            0 | 2020-05-23 07:47:23
```

What I want to do is to get a `progressive sum` of seconds from the first to the next row.

```
 id | track_seg_id |        time         |        prog         
----+--------------+---------------------+---------------------
  1 |            0 | 2020-05-23 07:45:32 | 0
  2 |            0 | 2020-05-23 07:46:04 | 32
  3 |            0 | 2020-05-23 07:46:53 | 81
  4 |            0 | 2020-05-23 07:46:58 | 86
  5 |            0 | 2020-05-23 07:47:03 | 91
  6 |            0 | 2020-05-23 07:47:08 | 96
  7 |            0 | 2020-05-23 07:47:11 | 99
  8 |            0 | 2020-05-23 07:47:16 | 104
  9 |            0 | 2020-05-23 07:47:20 | 108
 10 |            0 | 2020-05-23 07:47:23 | 111
```

I hit different resources, [calculate cumulative sum running total](https://popsql.com/learn-sql/postgresql/how-to-calculate-cumulative-sum-running-total-in-postgresql) and [calculating cumulative sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22841206/calculating-cumulative-sum-in-postgresql) ,  but I wasn't able to solve this problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you mean “seconds”, not “minutes”, and your values are slightly off.

If my suspicion is right, you could do it with the window function `first_value` and use `extract` to extract the number of seconds:

```
SELECT *,
       EXTRACT(epoch FROM
               time - first_value(time) OVER (ORDER BY time)
              )
FROM mytable;

 id | track_seg_id |        time         | date_part 
----+--------------+---------------------+-----------
  1 |            0 | 2020-05-23 07:45:32 |         0
  2 |            0 | 2020-05-23 07:46:04 |        32
  3 |            0 | 2020-05-23 07:46:53 |        81
  4 |            0 | 2020-05-23 07:46:58 |        86
  5 |            0 | 2020-05-23 07:47:03 |        91
  6 |            0 | 2020-05-23 07:47:08 |        96
  7 |            0 | 2020-05-23 07:47:11 |        99
  8 |            0 | 2020-05-23 07:47:16 |       104
  9 |            0 | 2020-05-23 07:47:20 |       108
 10 |            0 | 2020-05-23 07:47:23 |       111
(10 rows)
```

Comment: thanks @Laurenz Albe (I also corrected the question). Your solution is the same of @Lennard. Is there any difference in using the `EXTRACT` function once or twice?

Comment: My solution is slightly simpler and cheaper, but that's maybe not even measurable.

Comment: @matteo I choose my solution due to inexperience with time handling in PostgreSQL. However, I noticed that my solution seems to introduce an error for fractions of seconds, where as Laurenz does not. See: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=c4da92b14816a5add5931f8ffb2d79a2

Comment: @Lennart - any idea what's causing this error?

Comment: @Vérace Probably rounding errors - `EXTRACT` returns `double precision`.

Comment: @Verace, I would guess on floating-point errors, but I have nothing to back that up with.

Answer (score 4):

One way to do it:

```
select extract(EPOCH from ts) 
     - extract(EPOCH from first_value(ts) over (order by ts))
from t;
```

Comment: thanks @Lennart for the answer. It was very helpful